# Invoking function with string argument with lldb: how?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, lldb

I am unable to use lldb to invoke simple, non-templated functions that take string arguments. Is there any way to get lldb to understand the C++ datatype "string", which is a commonly used datatype in C++ programs?

The sample source code here just creates a simple class with a few constructors, and then calls them (includes of "iostream" and "string" omitted):

```
using namespace std;

struct lldbtest{
  int bar=5;
  lldbtest(){bar=6;}
  lldbtest(int foo){bar=foo;}
  lldbtest(string fum){bar=7;}
};

int main(){
  string name="fum";
  lldbtest x,y(3);
  cout<<x.bar<<y.bar<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When compiled on Mac Maverick with

```
g++ -g -std=c++11 -o testconstructor testconstructor.cpp
```

the program runs and prints the expected output of "63".

However, when a breakpoint is set in main just before the return statement, and attempt to invoke the constructor fails with a cryptic error message:

```
p lldbtest(string("hey there"))
error: call to a function              'lldbtest::lldbtest(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)' ('_ZN8lldbtestC1ENSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE') that is not present in the target
error: The expression could not be prepared to run in the target
```

Possibly relevant as well, the command:

```
 p lldbtest(name)
```

prints nothing at all.

Also, calling the constructor with a string literal also failed, the standard way:

```
p lldbtest("foo")
```

gives a similar long error:

```
 error: call to a function 
'lldbtest::lldbtest(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)' ('_ZN8lldbtestC1ENSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE') that is not present in the targeterror: The expression could not be prepared to run in the target
```

Is there any way to get lldb to understand and use the C++ "string" datatype? I have a number of functions taking string arguments and need a way to invoke these functions from the debugger. On a Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### THE PROBLEM

This is due to a subtle problem with your code, that boils down to the following wording from the C++ Standard:

> `7.1.2p3-4` **Function specifiers** `[dcl.fct.spec]`
>
> > A function defined within a class definition is an inline function.
> >
> > ...
> >
> > An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used, and shall have exactly the same definition in every case (3.2).

Your constructor, `lldbtest(std::string)` is defined within the body of `lldbtest` which means that it will *implicitly* be inline, which further means that the compiler will not generate any code for it, unless it is used in the *translation unit*.

Since the definition must be present in *every* translation unit that potentially calls it we can imagine the compiler saying; "*heck, I don't need to do this.. if someone else uses it, they will generate the code*".

*lldb* will look for a function definition which doesn't exist, since `gcc` didn't generate one; because you didn't use it.

---

#### THE SOLUTION

If we change the definition of `lldbtest` to the following I bet it will work as you intended:

```
struct lldbtest{
  int bar=5;
  lldbtest();
  lldbtest(int foo);
  lldbtest(string fum);
};

lldbtest::lldbtest() { bar=6; }
lldbtest::lldbtest(int) { bar=7; }
lldbtest::lldbtest(string) { bar=8; }
```

---

**But.. what about** `p lldbtest(name)`**?**

The command `p` in `lldb` is used to `print*` information, but it can also be used to evaluate *expressions*.

`lldbtest(name)` will not call the constructor of `lldbtest` with a variable called *name*, it's equivalent of **declaring** a variable called *name* of type `lldbtest`; ie. `lldbtest name` is sementically equivalent.

Comment: Great answer and thanks for the information. Indeed you are right: changing the function as you suggested fixed the problem.

Comment: In the real code though, the constructor was defined outside the class. It's just, the real code has many files and many classes and is hard to present as an example. But in the real code, I stopped the debugger at some point and the attempted to call the constructor with a string argument, and got the failure. Do you have any sense of why that might be? I cannot seem to reproduce on a small example. BTW how do you call lldbtest(name) from lldb?

Comment: @kdog the standard says that `(lidbtest)(name)` cannot be interpreted as a declaration, so `p (libdtest)(name)` would create a temporary of `libdtest` initialized with `name`. Without seeing the *real code*, there's no way to know, but is the real code perhaps using a class template?

Comment: I've been able to reproduce the issue with two small files, which I will post in another question, since you perfectly answered this question. And no, this particular function is not using a template - except, of course, indirectly via "string", which is a template.

Comment: @kdog let me know when you have posted the question and I'll try to bring some insight on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Going to answer the asked question here instead of addressing the problem with the op's code. Especially since this took me a while to figure out.

[Use a string in a function invocation in lldb in C++](https://gist.github.com/rstackhouse/67087c47a197dd70edd)

(This post helped greatly, and is a good read: [Dancing in The Debugger](http://www.objc.io/issues/19-debugging/lldb-debugging/))