# Invoking function with string argument from lldb: take 2

Tags: c++, string, c++11, lldb

I cannot seem to use lldb to invoke functions with string parameters , at times. In this question, [Invoking function with string argument with lldb: how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104814/invoking-function-with-string-argument-with-lldb-how) , I gave a simple test file illustrating the problem. A user answered that question to show how modifying the test file would fix the problem in that case.

But for more general situations I am still unable to invoke functions with string arguments from lldb.

To set this up though, I need to show two files. The first file is just like in the other question, a simple class lldbtest that defines a constructor taking a string argument. Then, another file defining a function in which the debugger will break.

The first file (without some #includes) looks like this:

```
 struct lldbtest{
   int bar=5;
   lldbtest();
   lldbtest(int foo);
   lldbtest(string &fum);
 };

 lldbtest::lldbtest() { bar=6; }
 lldbtest::lldbtest(int) { bar=7; }
 lldbtest::lldbtest(string&) { bar=8; }

 int main(){
   string name="fum";
   lldbtest x,y(3);
   cout<<x.bar<<y.bar<<endl;
   int zz=nothing();

   return 0;
 }
```

The second file looks like this:

```
 using namespace std;
 int nothing(){
   cout<<"hello there"<<endl;
   int n=0,m=1,r=2;
   return m+r+n;
 }
```

Now, when I set a breakpoint at the return statement in the second file, and evaluate:

```
p lldbtest(string("bar"))
```

I get a long error message that is quite difficult to post here but looks like this:

```
error: no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'string' (aka 'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >') to 'lldbtest'
 note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'string' (aka 'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >') to 'const lldbtest' for 1st argument
note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'string' (aka 'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >') to 'lldbtest' for 1st argument
note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'string' (aka 'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >') to 'int' for 1st argument
note: candidate constructor not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument
note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

Wow, the error message is longer than the code.

Anyway, my question is: how can I invoke functions/constructors with string parameters from lldb, from a file other than the one where the constructor was defined/declared, as here?

compilation was with g++ -g -std=c++11 . I used these same options to link the object files, also with g++ on a Mac.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### *Temporaries* cannot bind to *lvalue references*

The problem is that a *temporary*, `string ("bar")`, cannot bind to a *lvalue reference*, which is what the constructor you wish to use has as an argument; in other words, there's no direct issue with `lldb` in this case.

```
lldbtest::lldbtest(string &fum); // cannot be called with a temporary
```

To fix the problem you can change the constructor, or introduce a new one, that accepts a `string const&` or just a `string`, which will be suitable for the temporary passed during `p lldbtest(string("bar"))`:

```
lldbtest::lldbtest(string const&fum); // can bind to a temporary
lldbtest::lldbtest(string fum2);      // will copy the argument, safe to use with
                                      // lvalue and rvalues (temporaries)
```

---

If you try to have the same line of code in `main` you will see that the compiler won't accept what you are trying to do either:

```
lldbtest temporary (string ("bar")); // illegal, no suitable overload found
```

---

#### A little example

Which can further be explained with the following little snippet:

```
void func (std::string&) {
  // ...
}

int main () {
  func (std::string ("bar"));
}
```

```
foo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cpp:8:28: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::string&
                     {aka std::basic_string<char>&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::string
                     {aka std::basic_string<char>}’
   func (std::string ("bar"));
                            ^
foo.cpp:3:6: note: in passing argument 1 of ‘void func(std::string&)’
 void func (std::string&) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You would not believe how long I spent trying to figure this out, and it was all just one character.  Anyway that completely fixed the problem.